# Create a table with a dynamic number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, dynamic

What is the best way to implement a table with a variable number of columns and different types? 
(The number of columns is unknown)

We use a column of type `XML`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like using [document based databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) ,if possible. 
Technically you can not have a variable column designed table in SQL-Server.
By the way having a table based on columns bellow, may help:

```
EntityName: Full qualified entity name
EntityIdentifier: Id
PropertyName: 
PropertyType:
PropertyValue:
EntityStatus: may be useful on delete action
```

In these approach, like XML scenario you will need a parser to extract the entity. At list sql query will be more readable and updates will be more convenient.
Hope be helpful.

Comment: Tahnks,please give me Your Mail
to Send Complete Description 
My Emails: ESH_Computer110@yahoo
Esmaeil From Shiraz-Iran

Comment: mohsen.heydari@gmail.com is my email address, Its appreciated if the complete question and answer be negotiated on stack-overflow for others to use. by the way don't forget to mark the answer as [the answer of your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if fitting you.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you would create another table where the key, is a composite key of the ID and ColumnName.

Table Def :

```
ID        ColumnName        ColumnValue
```

The `Id` is the key from the primary table with a FK to enforce integrity.

You now have two choices make the datatype of the value a dumping ground and insert anything, or create a table like the above for each datatype you need.

Then you can write a view with a pivot to make this look like a normal table for queries etc.

Ps I don't suggest this will be a) the best solution or b) the quickest.

Comment: Isn't this EAV?  (for better or worse)

Comment: I suppose it kinda is, hence my suggest's a) and b)